# Excel: Power Query Editor: Data Source from Web has Changing Columns

Tags: excel, powerquery, dynamic-columns

I have a spreadsheet that has data for games played in a video game, sorted by hero, winrates, etc.  In excel, using data source from web, and using the website here: [https://www.heroesprofile.com/Global/Hero/?timeframe_type=minor&timeframe=2.50.1.79515&game_type=sl&map=Alterac+Pass](https://www.heroesprofile.com/Global/Hero/?timeframe_type=minor&timeframe=2.50.1.79515&game_type=sl&map=Alterac%20Pass) populates as it should under table 0.

The problem is once new data is entered to the website, the table column headers change; then the refresh-able data source on excel gives errors such as this: Expression.Error: The column '48.59 Win Rate %' of the table wasn't found.  (The winrate changed when new logs were uploaded; so I think the column header is the issue since it can't find it anymore.)

Is there a way in advanced editor to set it so the column headers just refresh along with all the rest of the data?  Or a work around of some kind?

```
let
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://www.heroesprofile.com/Global/Hero/?timeframe_type=minor&timeframe=2.50.1.79515&game_type=sl&map=Hanamura+Temple")),
    Data0 = Source{0}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{"AVG Hero", type text}, {"48.59 Win Rate %", type number}, {"18.01 Popularity %", type number}, {"11.36 Pick Rate %", type number}, {"6.65 Ban Rate %", type number}, {"66 | -29 Influence", Int64.Type}, {"989 Games Played", Int64.Type}, {"Avg Win Rate", type text}, {"", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

The number of columns and rows rarely ever change if there's a way to set those generically.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the type of contents of the columns does not change, you can load the data and remove any processing steps that Power Query adds.

If Power Query recognises the first row of the data as column headers, you can do the following:

- manually execute the ribbon command to treat headers as first row
- manually rename the columns to the desired column name
- remove the first row (which has the headers)

[image]

Now you are in control of the column names and can have the same column name consistently, even if the column name changes in the source.

Screenshot of the result in PQ
[image]

Code copied from the Advanced Editor

```
let
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://www.heroesprofile.com/Global/Hero/?timeframe_type=minor&timeframe=2.50.1.79515&game_type=sl&map=Hanamura+Temple")),
    Data0 = Source{0}[Data],
    #"Demoted Headers" = Table.DemoteHeaders(Data0),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Demoted Headers",{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", type text}, {"Column6", type text}, {"Column7", type text}, {"Column8", type text}, {"Column9", type text}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Column1", "AVG Hero"}, {"Column2", "Win Rate"}, {"Column3", "Popularity"}, {"Column4", "Pick Rate"}, {"Column5", "Ban rate"}, {"Column6", "Influence"}, {"Column7", "Games Played"}, {"Column8", "Avg win rate"}}),
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Renamed Columns",1)
in
    #"Removed Top Rows"
```

Comment: Thanks!  This didn't seem to work though.  ><  I do think the removing the 4th row was the answer and seems to work!

Comment: Removing the fourth row is what I mean with  "remove any processing steps that Power Query adds." After that you still have column names that are changing and cannot be used further down. I'm showing you how to get column names that don't change all the time. And it works.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks!  I'll try this as well.  Sorry missed that!

Answer (score 0):

Remove 4th row?

```
let
  Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://www.heroesprofile.com/Global/Hero/?timeframe_type=minor&timeframe=2.50.1.79515&game_type=sl&map=Hanamura+Temple")),
Data0 = Source{0}[Data]
in Data0
```